How to properly call asynchronous request in Python without aiohttp
This may be a silly question, but I designed a small python script to synchronize two applications, designed to run in a HubSpot custom coded action. This environment runs for a maximum of 20 seconds with a maximum 128MB of memory.
To optimize for speed, my code fetches records asynchronously using asyncio.to_thread on get request of the requests package. I think this is not the correct way to fetch requests asynchronously, as it relies on multiple threads (right?).
Normally I would use aiohttp for fetching asynchronously, but the environment only has the regular requests package installed. Can I reproduce the aiohttp functionality without installing the package?

asyncio won't be able to schedule requests functions because they use blocking sockets. requests allows you to create custom adapter classes. Adapters are responsible for sending the actual request and receiving the response, so your custom adapter can return the request instead of sending it, and then you can send the request using asyncio streams in separate tasks instead.

Also, if you want to avoid threads due to environment limitations, tasks might not alleviate the problem.
